# Naive Bayes: Continuous and Categorical Predictors

Tags: naive-bayes

It's my understanding that most types of common classifiers (Support Vector Machine, for example) can take a mixture of categorical and continuous predictors.

However, this doesn't seem to be true for Naive Bayes, since I need to specify the likelihood distribution a priori.

What should I do if I want to run Naive Bayes for a mixture of categorical and continuous predictors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use any kind of predictor in a naive Bayes classifier, as long as you can specify a conditional probability $p(x|y)$ of the predictor value $x$ given the class $y$. Since naive Bayes assumes predictors are conditionally independent given the class, you can mix-and-match different likelihood models for each predictor according to any prior knowledge you have about  it.

For example, you might know that $p(x|y)$ for some continuous predictor is normally distributed. Simply estimate the mean and variance for this variable under each class in the training set; then use PDF of the Normal distribution to estimate $p(x|y)$ for new unlabeled instances. Similarly, you can use the sufficient statistics and PDF of any other continuous distribution as appropriate.

If some other predictor in the classifier is categorical, that's fine. Simply estimate $p(x|y)$ using a Bernoulli or multinomial event model as you normally would, and multiply the two conditional probabilities together in the final prediction (since they are assumed to be independent anyway).

**Side Note:** It isn't strictly the case that SVMs and other discriminative linear models take a mixture of categorical and continuous predictors. You can interpret SVMs as only taking continuous predictors, with values in {0,1} for categorical variables as a special case.

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on.  The problem is that in the Python library sklearn's implementation of Naive Bayes, you have to specify the likelihood distribution as Gaussian, Binomial, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. You could play a trick by fitting a different classifier for each subset of predictor types (Gaussian, Binomial, etc.) using the different naive Bayes implementations. Then multiply their posterior distributions together and re-normalize to make predictions. Again, since the predictors are assumed to be conditionally independent, this should give you the same answer... though it's a little sloppy from a software engineering perspective. :)

Comment: Ok, let me make sure I understood you properly.  The new predictor, created by the product of their posterior distributions, would just be a single number, right?  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you can just multiply if the probability of each class is equal.  Otherwise, you have to normalize by the probability of the class.  Right?

Comment: You know what... I spoke too soon. The nb.predict_proba(X) method will return posteriors normalized over all classes. The correct thing would be to multiply the *unnormalized* probabilities. So it looks like the only way to mix predictor types with sklearn is to roll your own subclass of BaseNB that knows how to treat the differepent predictors differently.

Comment: But if the probabilities of each class is roughly equal, it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Specifically, nb.predict_proba(x1) should give P(C1|x1)...P(CN|x1).  Can't I just then use the following formula to combine posterior probabilities?  
P(C1|x1,x2)=P(C1|x1)*P(C1|x2)/P(C1)

(see http://www.mpia-hd.mpg.de/Gaia/publications/probcomb_TN.pdf)

Comment: You can certainly do this, and it would be an ensemble classifier, but it still isn't exactly the same prediction as a single "mixed" naive Bayes model, since nb.predict_proba(x1) returns normalized class marginal probabilities. Say we have two classes {0,1}, a continuous variable $x$, and a discrete variable $z$. The "proper" posterior of class 1 for the mixed NB classifier is $p(1|x,z) = \frac{p(1)p(x|1)p(z|1)}{p(1)p(x|1)p(z|1)+p(0)p(x|0)p(z|0)}$. If you expand out the equation for the product of two differen NB classifiers in this case, you'll see that the math is different.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach to handling continuous predictors is to "bin" your continuous variables:

A common example is to split time of day *(continuous, numeric)* into AM and PM, for instance.

You can potentially capture more information by increasing the # bins *(e.g. split 24 hours into 4 6-hour periods)*; however, this also increases your model's sensitivity to noisy data so you need to be careful.

Based on my experience I'd recommend this approach if you have one/few continuous predictors among many categorical predictors.

Comment: Would you use a Multinomial or Bernoulli Naive Bayes model for your time example?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this as sketched above - "*Another simple approach to handling continuous predictors is to bin your continuous variables*" - is available in a ready-to-use ***webservice***.

Real-valued numeric variables are 'binned' while maximizing the retained discriminative performance with respect to the classifier outcomes to predict. After this preprocessing step, the classifier is built 'on-the-fly', and its generalization ability tested with *N-fold cross validation*.

You can try this ***webservice*** yourself at [Insight classifiers](https://insight-classifiers.com).

When you want real insight into how classification takes place in your domain, you need to substitute continuous-valued classifiers such as neural networks and support-vector machines with discrete classifiers.

A multivariate mixture distribution that comprises ***discrete*** and ***continuous*** *predictive variables* - any mapping of this to the classification outcomes involves complex probability integrals [Egmont-Petersen et al](https://www.egmont-petersen.nl/science/Journal-papers/Egmont-Petersen-NN-1998.pdf). And in most classification domains, these probability densities are not Gaussian.

So performance-retaining discretization of the *predictive* variables ensures a distribution-free (non-parametric) classifier, which is also a **white-box**. This means that you can comprehend the classifier and thereby the underlying domain.