# Does Naive Bayes assume normality?

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, assumptions, naive-bayes

I came across [this paper](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/28135/) about Naive Bayes that states

> [Naive Bayes] is based on another common simplifying assumption: the values of numeric attributes are normally distributed within each class.

Is that true? Does Naive Bayes require that you assume continuous predictors are normal?

From [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93932/90427) and my experience, I thought that you can use any distribution to describe your predictors, normal or otherwise. Am I missing something? Is the paper just badly worded, e.g. it should say "is *commonly* based on a normality assumption" instead of "is based on a normality assumption?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On its own, Naive Bayes does *not* assume the normal distribution. The heart of Naive Bayes is the heroic conditional independence assumption:
$$P(x \mid X, C) = P(x \mid C)$$

Gaussian Naive Bayes assumes the normal distribution...

Comment: Is the paper badly worded / incorrect then? Do they just mean "Naive Bayes *often* assumes normality?"

Comment: @Qroid Without reading anything (so I could be wrong), my guess is that they mean Gaussian Naive Bayes. Often times you need to read text reasonably rather than explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't mean to nit pick. Just wondered if I understood correctly.

Comment: It perform well in case of categorical input variables compared to numerical variable(s). For numerical variable, normal distribution is assumed (bell curve, which is a strong assumption).